# How to jump to next word in vim when pascal case is used?

Tags: vim

I would like to move carret to `Bar` in `FooBarFizzBuzz` in vim. How to do that?

How to make `w` 'pascal case aware'? Is there any other stroke already for this?

Comment: do you know about the 'f' command?  I find it covers the cases that I'm looking for regarding camelcase words.  In your example, if you're on the Foo and want to go to Bar, press `fB`.  If you're on Fizz, you press `FB` to go backwards.  If you are on Foo and want to go to Buzz, type `2fB`.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang I'm not. I'm quite a newbie. will take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_through_camel_case_words

It explains various ways to set up the behavior you're describing (with increasing levels of complexity / completeness) as well as a link to a script that appears to have more configuration options). The examples are for mapping the arrow keys but you could presumably remap w and such if you liked.

Answer (score 0):

How's this for size:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_through_camel_case_words